# How to get SonarQube to scan JavaScript/TypeScript source code inside of a Java project?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, maven, sonarqube

I have a Maven Java project that builds the Java files and JavaScript (TypeScript) files all at the same time in one Maven project (single module project). How do I get the SonarQube Maven plugin to scan not only the Java source code but also the JavaScript/TypeScript source code? At the moment SonarQube only recognizes the project as Java and ignores scanning any JavaScript/TypeScript source files.

Answer (score 0):

[SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/) recognizes the project type and base on it generate `sonar.sources` property. If you have a `jar` project then it sets it to `pom.xml,src/main/java` (if I remember correctly). You can overwrite the property in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>pom.xml,src/main</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

Now all you Java code and JavaScript/TypeScript code should be scanned (I assumed you keep `*.js` files `src/main/resources` or `src/main/javascript`).